# How can I check if my derivative for an implicit function is correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For explicit functions I can calculate the derivative at a certian point using the original function: $$\frac{f(1+0.1) - f(1)}{0.1}$$

And then use $\frac{d}{dx}f(1)$ to check if the function is correct. But what can I do for implicit funcions? how can I calculate the change then compare it with my derivative function

Edit: for example if I was asked to differentiate
$f(x)=x^2+\tanh(x)$ and if I am unsure about my answer I could type in on the calculator:
$$\frac{f(5+0.000001) - f(5)}{0.000001}$$ and then check my $\frac{d}{dx}f(5)$ they should be approximately equal.
My question is if I have an implicit function like $$xy^3=\tan(x+2y)-(x^2-1)$$ and after I differentiate it how can I check if it is correct

Comment: Can you provide us with an example to discuss?

Comment: I added one, hope it is a clear

Comment: Ok. For this case, if you want to evaluate the derivative at x=5, you also need to have the corresponding y value. In this case, you can find y for x=5.000000001, then apply the derivative quotient as well. Finding the y value for a corresponding given x value for this example will be tedious though. I think you need numerical approximation for this example.:)

Comment: You can first calculate the real derivative for a pair of $(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation, then choose a $\Delta x$, then test if $\left(x+\Delta x, y + \Delta x \frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ approximately satisfies the equation.

Comment: Do I have to get the corresponding y in this case too? or can be the y be any value? if so can I just select x and y to have the same value? Edit: or even 0 to get rid of the calculation on the calculator?

Comment: If you use the method by peterwhy, you need to find the value of y for that corresponding value of x as well.

Comment: I guess this answers my question, I guess I won't check during exams because it will take a long time but I can still check when solving problems. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first calculate the real derivative for a pair of $(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation, then choose a $Δx$, then test if $\left(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ approximately satisfies the equation.

For example, looks like $\left(0, -\pi/8\right)$ is a root of your equation. So you can choose $x' = 0.000001$ and find the corresponding $y'$ using the derivative:

$$\begin{align*}
3xy^2\frac{dy}{dx} + y^3 &= \sec^2(x+2y)\left(1+2\frac{dy}{dx}\right) -2x\\
3xy^2\frac{dy}{dx} -2\sec^2(x+2y)\frac{dy}{dx} &= \sec^2(x+2y) -2x - y^3\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{\sec^2(x+2y) -2x - y^3}{3xy^2 -2\sec^2(x+2y)}\\
\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{\left(0,-\frac\pi8\right)} &= \frac{2+\frac{\pi^3}{8^3}}{-4}
\end{align*}$$

So let $$y' = -\frac\pi8 +\frac{2+\frac{\pi^3}{8^3}}{-4}\cdot0.000001 \approx -0.392699596839\ldots$$

$$LHS = x'\left(y'\right)^3 = -6.0559372465\ldots×10^{-8}$$
$$RHS = \tan\left(x'+2y'\right)-\left(x'\right)^2 + 1 = -6.056\ldots×10^{-8}$$

And hope it is close enough...

Comment: Do you know how to check a implicit double derivative?

Comment: You wrote that "check if $\left(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$" satisfies the equation. Did you mean $\left(\Delta x,y+\Delta x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$?

Answer (score 3):

Great question - this sort of things shows up all the time when writing code to solve constrained optimization problems.

The standard strategy is as follows. First, you need a mechanism to solve for $y$ given $x$. For example, you could use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), or [bisection search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), or whatever. I recommend Newton's method with [backtracking linesearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search). You can check the correctness of your solver code by plugging $x,y$ into the original equation and verifying that the residual is zero.

Then that complicated solver code is your function $y=f(x)$, and you can check your derivative with finite differences $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ with a random direction $h$, like you mention in the original post.

To make sure that your code doesn't converge to a different root when you compute $y_2 = f(x+h)$, use your original $y_1 = f(x)$ as the initial guess in your solver.

Another tip is to choose several different finite difference stepsizes, say $10^{-1}, 10^{-2}, 10^{-3} \dots, 10^{-7}$, and plot the error in the derivative on a log-log plot. The error should linearly decrease until around the square root of machine epsilon - for doubles machine epsilon is around $10^{-15}$, so usually you will see a straight line going down until the step size is around $10^{-7}$, after which point numerical rounding takes over. If your code is working, you should get something that looks like the following plot.
[image: finite difference check log-log plot]

Comment: I was coding a simple derivative calculator in c# but had some problems, I look forward the day I will be able to add implicit functions with so much options like limits and graphs

Answer (score 1):

For an implicit function F(x,y) the formula is:

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = - \dfrac{F_x}{F_y}   ...(1*) $$

$$ F = x\, y^3 + (x^2-1) - \tan ( x+ 2 y) $$

$$ F_x =  y^3 + 2 x - \sec^2 ( x+ 2 y) ;  F_y = 3 x y^2 -2 \sec^2 ( x+ 2 y) ; $$

and plug them in, to evaluate $\frac {dy}{dx}$ at any (x,y).

How does one get this result?

Differentiate   F(x,y)= 0 ; Total differential

$$ F_x dx + F_y dy = 0.$$

To check by calculation at any point, hold x constant and compute $F_y $ differential the way you stated, then  hold y constant and compute  $ F_x $ same way, use (1*).